# Determine the basis of a subset V in a vector space of R3

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, provability

I have to determine a basis of a given polinomyal subset. V is defined as:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLIYn.png)

I don't know how to start, maybe it could be helpfull to know that V is the subset of polynomial in the following form:

`(x+1)g(x)` with g(x) polynomial with degree at most 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$P (x)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d $$ is an element of $V $ if only if

$$P (-1)=-a+b-c+d=0$$
thus
$$d=a+c-b $$
and then
$$P (x)=a (x^3+1)+b (x^2-1)+c (x+1) $$

$$\implies V=span (x^3+1,x^2-1,x+1) $$

theses polynoms are independant and forms a base of $V $.

Comment: span{(x+1)x^2, (x+1)x, (x+1)} is a correct solution?

Answer (score 0):

$e_1 = x+1\\
e_2 = (x+1)x = x^2 + x$

etc.